# JqGrid Extension With Yii2

Tags: php, jquery, yii, jqgrid

Fairly simple question, I think.

I am trying to use jqGrid with a Yii2 application, but I am having difficulty getting it to pull the data from my SQL database.

Here is my model

```
class People extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord

public static function tableName()
{
    return 'people';
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['dob', 'CURDATE'], 'safe'],
        [['age'], 'integer'],
        [['firstname', 'surname'], 'string', 'max' => 50]
    ];
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'firstname' => 'Firstname',
        'surname' => 'Surname',
        'dob' => 'Dob',
        'age' => 'Age',
        'CURDATE' => 'Curdate',
    ];
}
```

Here is my controller jqgrid action

```
use himiklab\jqgrid\actions\JqGridActiveAction;

public function actions()
{
    return [
        'jqgrid' => [
            'class' => JqGridActiveAction::className(),
            'model' => People::className(),
            'columns' => ['id', 'firstname', 'surname', 'dob', 'age', 'CURDATE']
        ],
    ];
}
```

Here is my view jqgrid widget

```
use himiklab\jqgrid\JqGridWidget;

<?= JqGridWidget::widget([
    'requestUrl' => 'admin/jqgrid',
    'gridSettings' => [
        'colNames' => ['ID', 'Firstname', 'Lastname', 'DOB', 'Age', 'CurDate'],
        'colModel' => [
            ['name' => 'id', 'index' => 'id', 'editable' => true],
            ['name' => 'firstname', 'index' => 'firstname', 'editable' => true],
            ['name' => 'surname', 'index' => 'surname', 'editable' => true]
            ['name' => 'dob', 'index' => 'dob', 'editable' => true]
            ['name' => 'age', 'index' => 'age', 'editable' => true]
            ['name' => 'CURDATE', 'index' => 'CURDATE', 'editable' => true]
        ],
        'rowNum' => 15,
        'autowidth' => true,
        'height' => 'auto',
    ],
    'pagerSettings' => [
        'edit' => true,
        'add' => true,
        'del' => true,
        'search' => ['multipleSearch' => true]
    ],
    'enableFilterToolbar' => true
]); ?>
```

These are just snippets from the relative php pages.

Now when I render the view nothing shows at all. Any ideas what I am missing?

Let me know if you need any more info.

And this is the link and explanation of how to use the
[jqgrid extension for Yii 2](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-jqgrid-widget/)

Comment: What have you done so far to debug the code and pinpoint the problem?

Comment: Not much, what can you suggest I do, to be honest I am fairly new to Yii and the extensions that come with Yii, so any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

What controller is beeing used? Is it AdminController? If not, your widgets 'requestUrl' needs to be 'people/jqgrid' or equivalent.

Comment: I am using the default SiteController, which is linked to my People Model. So I should change it to `site/jqgrid`?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I have given it a rest for now, am going to come back to it in the coming week. Will let you know if I manage to progress with it any further then.

Comment: So, you had any luck?